# Unable to apply the new syntax of `using` for StreamWriter

Tags: c#, using, streamwriter

On [MSDN about `using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), there's the new syntax presented. I like it and started to apply it.

Instead of

```
using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memory, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
  {
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(crypto))
    {
      writer.Write(text);
    }
  }
}
```

I can now go

```
using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
using ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
using MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
using CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memory, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(crypto))
  writer.Write(text);
```

However, I can't make the last part work the new way. For some reason, `StreamWriter` won't allow me to do this.

```
using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
using ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
using MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
using CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memory, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(crypto);
writer.Write(text);
```

I can't really see why. There might be a technical explanation to it in the linked article, as they discuss requirements and limitations. Regrettably, I simply fail to see where they say it and what's implied.

By Skeety's request - full reproducible sample.

```
public void Test()
{
  string text = "hakuna matata";
  string code = "1234567890abcdef";
  byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(code);
  byte[] iv = key[..16];

  using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
  using ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
  using MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
  using CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memory, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

  using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(crypto);
  writer.Write(text);
  //writer.Flush();

  //using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(crypto))
  //  writer.Write(text);

  string output = Convert.ToBase64String(memory.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Your new code only disposes the writer *after* the `string output = Convert.ToBase64String(memory.ToArray());` call, whereas before I assume it was disposed before. It's still *getting* disposed, but at a different point. Note that as this is a difference between before and after, it would be useful for the minimal example to show the minimal *before* change as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your old code, all your resources, including the `StreamWriter` and `CryptoStream`, get disposed implicitly at the end of their `using` block. Upon being disposed, any pending content would get flushed to the `MemoryStream`. Thus, when you inspect the `MemoryStream` *after* the end of these `using` blocks, it would be correctly populated.

In your new code, the new `using` syntax means that the resources only get disposed at the end of the *enclosing* block – in this case, the parent method. Thus, when you inspect the `MemoryStream` within the same method, you are doing so *before* `StreamWriter` and `CryptoStream` have been disposed, and hence *before* their contents have been flushed to the `MemoryStream`.

For the sake of demonstration, calling `Dispose` on the `StreamWriter` just before reading the `MemoryStream` would restore the correct behavior:

```
using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(crypto);
writer.Write(text);
writer.Dispose()
string output = Convert.ToBase64String(memory.ToArray());
```

That said, I would recommend against the above, since you're mixing explicit `Dispose` calls with implicit ones generated by the `using`.

Alternatively, you could consume the `MemoryStream` from an *outer* method, hence ensuring the inner method would have disposed its resources at the end of its execution:

```
public void Test()
{
     var memory = TestInner();
     string output = Convert.ToBase64String(memory.ToArray());
}

private MemoryStream TestInner()
{
    string text = "hakuna matata";
    string code = "1234567890abcdef";
    byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(code);
    byte[] iv = key[..16];

    using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
    using ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
    using MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
    using CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memory, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(crypto);
    writer.Write(text); 

    return memory;
}
```

However, I would prefer using the old `using` blocks for clarity in situations like this.

Comment: Adding a `using` to the variable declaration when one is going to call `Dispose()` anyway is redundant. It would suffice to just call `Flush()` on the writer. Alternatively, if one needs a shorter lifetime than the scope of the variable, that should be done explicitly with an old-style `using`. Recommending to mix the new-style with an explicit call to `Dispose()` just seems wrong to me.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: "It would suffice to just call `Flush()` on the writer." ← That was the first thing I suggested in the comments. Surprisingly, it doesn't work. But I agree with your point; I'll clarify that the `Dispose` is just meant as a demonstration.

Comment: Huh...well, if `Flush()` doesn't work, there's something else going on that hasn't been diagnosed yet and `Dispose()` is just sweeping the bug under the rug. I don't know much about `CryptoStream` but I wouldn't be surprised if _that's_ the object that needs to be disposed. Other similar objects, like `GzipStream`, `ZipArchive`, etc. only finalize the data when the object is disposed. `StreamWriter` will dispose the underlying stream unless specified otherwise, so disposing it probably causes the other dispose to work. The other one being non-optional unlike `StreamWriter`'s.